# Tracing Cubic Interpolated Path

Tags: algorithm, math, interpolation

I'm smoothing a path via cubic interpolation, based on [this math](http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/interpolation):

```
mu2 = mu*mu;
a0 = -0.5*x0 + 1.5*x1 - 1.5*x2 + 0.5*x3;
a1 = x0 - 2.5*x1 + 2*x2 - 0.5*x3;
a2 = -0.5*x0 + 0.5*x2;
a3 = x1;

interpolated_x = (a0*mu*mu2+a1*mu2+a2*mu+a3)
```

When I try to trace a segment on the path by iterating `mu` from 0.0 to 1.0, the distances are not equal. In the screenshot, the red points are the points of the path, the green and blue points are control points to calculate the curve.

[image]

Is there a way I can calculate a percentage of distance covered of a segment that gives me equal distances?

(I want to calculate a movement on this path, that has the same speed and depends on the percentage of distance covered. In this way, the movement would be faster in the middle of each segments.)

Comment: Thats is not the formula for linear interpolation. Either [edit] the title to use the correct interpolation name, or show the code that applies in your case. The linked `LinearInterpolate()` function would give you constant speed.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Thanks for the hint, I hope the terming is correct now.

Answer (score 0):

This function interpolates between `x_1` and `x_2` for values `mu=0..1`. But if you calculate the speed `xp = diff(x, mu)` at the end points you will find

```
xp_1 = (x_2-x_0)/2                    xp_2 = (x_3-x_1)/2
```

So if the speed isn't equal and the ends points, it is going to vary by location. Even if it was equal at the ends points with `v = (x_2-x_0)/2 = (x_3-x_1)/2` or

```
x_0 = x_2 -2 v                       x_3 = 2 v + x_1
```

or the speed function

```
xp = v - 6*mu*(v+x_1-x_2) + 6*mu2*(v+x_1-x_2)
```

To make the speed constant, `v+x_1-x_2 = 0`, or `v=x_2-x_1` which yields the linear interpolation function

```
xp = x_2 - x_1
x = x_1 + mu*(x_2-x_1)
```

So to keep the spacing equal, you must use linear interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

To provide equal spacing, you need to get curve segments of equal length. Note that curve length (both for the whole curve and for it's fragment) might be calculated using integration ([in parametric form from here](https://www.mathwords.com/a/arc_length_of_a_curve.htm))

```
ds = Sqrt((dx/dt)^2+(dy/dt)^2)*dt
L = Integral{t=a..b} (ds), where t = 0..1 for overall length.
```

Sadly for cubic curves such integral (here it is `elliptic`) cannot be solved analytically and should be calculated numerically. It is well-known problem for Bezier curves, for instance.

So to build equal-length segments, you need to numerically find length L of the whole curve, find `l[i]=i*L/n` for position of i-th point and numerically find (for example, with binary search) parameter for this position.